# Kitten can't speak

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running through the [mongoose quickstart](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) and my app keeps dying on `fluffy.speak()` with the error `TypeError: Object { name: 'fluffy', _id: 509f3377cff8cf6027000002 } has no method 'speak'`

My (slightly modified) code from the tutorial:

```
"use strict";

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    });
    var Kitten = db.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
    var silence = new Kitten({name: 'Silence'});
    console.log(silence.name);
    kittySchema.methods.speak = function() {
        var greeting = this.name ? "Meow name is" + this.name : "I don't have a name";
        console.log(greeting);
    };

    var fluffy = new Kitten({name: 'fluffy'});

    fluffy.speak();

    fluffy.save(function(err) {
        console.log('meow');
    });

    function logResult(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    }

    Kitten.find(logResult);
    Kitten.find({name: /fluff/i }, logResult);
});
```

Comment: Lol, the title just screams "OFF TOPIC!" :P

Comment: Yes I can! I'm speaking right now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `db.model`, the model is compiled from your schema.  It's at that point that `schema.methods` are added to the model's prototype.  So you need to define any methods on the schema *before* you make a model out of it.

```
// ensure this method is defined before...
kittySchema.methods.speak = function() {
    var greeting = this.name ? "Meow name is" + this.name : "I don't have a name";
    console.log(greeting);
}

// ... this line.
var Kitten = db.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

// methods added to the schema *afterwards* will not be added to the model's prototype
kittySchema.methods.bark = function() {
    console.log("Woof Woof");
};

(new Kitten()).bark(); // Error!  Kittens don't bark.
```